# Jooq - Generate Kotlin DTO objects for each table

Tags: kotlin, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I have jooq generating Kotlin classes from a database (mysql) with no problem.

Here is my maven config:

```
                <configuration>
                    <generator>
                        <name>org.jooq.codegen.KotlinGenerator</name>
                        <database>
                            <inputSchema>itr</inputSchema>
                        </database>
                    </generator>
                </configuration>
```

According to the docs https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/kotlingenerator/, the kotlin generator `pojosAsKotlinDataClasses` is `true` by default, but this setup is not generating any `data class ...` classes.

I just want a plain DTO data class for each table in addition to the other classes generated.

My maven command is:

```
mvn -Djooq.codegen.jdbc.url='jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb' -Djooq.codegen.jdbc.username=root\
    -Djooq.codegen.jdbc.password=root -Djooq.codegen.target.packageName=com.example.module.domain\
    -Djooq.codegen.target.directory=src/main-generated/kotlin\
     generate-sources
```

I have a table called Role and I want a DTO like this:

```
data class RoleDTO(val id: String, val name: String, val description: String)
```

However, I'm just getting the following generated classes:

```
./DefaultCatalog.kt
./keys
./keys/Keys.kt
./Itr.kt
./tables
./tables/Role.kt
./tables/records
./tables/records/RoleRecord.kt
./tables/references
./tables/references/Tables.kt
```

None of these are a DTO like I would like. How do I do tell jooq to generate my DTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<pojosAsKotlinDataClasses/>` just governs the style of generated pojos, but you have to activate `<pojos/>` explicitly to get any data classes. See:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-pojos/

Comment: Very cool! Now - is there any way to name the pojo something different so that, for example, my itr_role table does not have 2 beans named ItrRole in the project? It would be really nice to have ItrRole as the Jooq TableImpl class and ItrRoleDTO as the Pojo...

Comment: @mikeb: Yes. Best answered in a new question!